# Is it possible to annotate a backing bean method to be called on a phase?

Tags: events, jsf, binding, jsf-2, phaselistener

I need an initializer method in the backing bean to be called after components are bind. @PostConstruct is called before component bindings. Is there any JSF annotation for methods which cause method call after component binding?

Currently it's possible to use something like `<f:view afterPhase="#{bean.initialize}">` or `<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{bean.initialize}" />` which requires code on page side and bean side. Is there any bean-side-only solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing like that in standard JSF API.

Closest what you can get is lazy loading in getter.

```
public UIComponent getSomeComponent() {
    if (!initialized(someComponent)) {
        initialize(someComponent);
    }
    return someComponent;
}
```

or lazy executing in setter.

```
public void setSomeComponent(UIComponent someComponent) {
    if (!initialized(someComponent)) {
        initialize(someComponent);
    }
    this.someComponent = someComponent;
}
```